# Extracting nvarchar value from XML in T-SQL: only one character returned

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

In my T-SQL procedure I'm trying to extract a string value from the XML node using the .value() method, like this:

```
declare @criteria xml;
set @criteria = N'<criterion id="DocName"><value>abcd</value></criterion>';

declare @val nvarchar;
set @val = @criteria.value('(criterion[@id="DocName"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar');

select @val;
```

I expected to get **'abcd'** as a result, but I surprisingly got just **'a'**.

So, the `value` method returns only the 1st character of the string. Can anybody tell me, what  am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

P.S. I'm using MS SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use nvarchar without size. From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx):

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the
>   CAST function, the default length is 30.

If you don't know exact length, you always can use `nvarchar(max)`:

```
declare @criteria xml;
set @criteria = N'<criterion id="DocName"><value>abcd</value></criterion>';

declare @val nvarchar(max);
set @val = @criteria.value('(criterion[@id="DocName"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');

select @val;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25537)</kbd>**