# Can't add a nvarchar to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

just look at this code ... its taking hours from me ... and still not working !!!

```
DECLARE @Code NVARCHAR
DECLARE @MaxCode BIGINT = 81000
SELECT @Code = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CONVERT(BIGINT,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@MaxCode),2,LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@MaxCode) - 1)))+1)
SELECT N'D' + @Code,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CONVERT(BIGINT,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@MaxCode),2,LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@MaxCode) - 1)))+1)
```

there are results, can u believe it :

```
D1 | 1001
```

i did try `SET` too, but nothing changed

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: i did expect D1001 for first column.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20180012/92546) answer helps to clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
DECLARE @Code NVARCHAR(2000)
```

And see what happens.

Comment: @MohammadHosseinGhaebi Please Mark this as the answer if it did helped you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not specifying the *Length* of `Nvarchar` while declaring `Variable` by default `1` will be its length

Declare `@Code NVARCHAR` will be same as `@Code NVARCHAR(1)`

---

If you are not specifying the *Length* of `Nvarchar` in `CAST/CONVERT` by default `30` will its length

`SELECT @Code = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,..)` will same as `SELECT @Code = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),..)`

---

So always use `NVARCHAR/Varchar` with proper lengths

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Code NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

I using max as the SQL SERVER will only reserve the memory for the amount of char instead of fixed number char eg DECLARE @Code NVARCHAR(1000) .